# How to find out every time a stored procedure has run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to find out every single time a stored procedure has run in the last X amount of days? There are ways to see the last time it ran, but what if I want to see the last X number of times.

I can't find anything when I searched. Any suggestions?

Comment: The usual way is to add some logging into the stored procedure, for example INSERT INTO SomeTable... But that will of course not reveal any executions of the stored procedure before you added your logging. Was that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you take advantage of the ability of Extended Events to capture a histogram. You can set it up like this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ProcedureExecutionCount]
ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed
    (SET collect_statement = (0)
     WHERE (
               [sqlserver].[equal_i_sql_unicode_string]([sqlserver].[database_name], N'AdventureWorks')
               AND [object_name] = N'AddressByCity'
           )
    )
    ADD TARGET package0.histogram
    (SET filtering_event_name = N'sqlserver.rpc_completed', source = N'object_name', source_type = (0));
```

That will now, only, ever, count the number of times that procedure, on that database, is executed. Nice, simple, clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. Visit here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/